# French bulldog lasting diarrhea

Tags: dogs

My 1.5 year old French Bulldog has come down with a case of diarrhea/loose stool for almost 3 weeks. All stools are now very loose, and sometimes completely liquid. On two nights in particular, he very frequently needed to go out, and ended up going out almost every 2 hours. I took him to the vet and they performed a stool inspection test, which they found no problems. They gave a medication to help form solid stool, but it wasn't completely effective (some days he'd have 50% solids, other days he'd be back to completely runny).

Nothing has changed in his diet or schedule, eating the same adult dog food that he has been eating for awhile now, and living the same lifestyle he always had. It doesn't appear to be affecting him in any other way: He's still in good spirits, loves to play, run, walk, has a good appetite, etc.

Just looking for suggestions on what to try next.

Comment: I would check for other "non food" he may have eaten, like a destroyed toy-parts, pot-plants or in the plants garden, or other stuff. Only to be sure, it is nothing he eats from time to time without your knowledge.